# VeeValidate v3 extend access to Vue data

Tags: vee-validate

I am trying to use VeeValidate v3 to validate that a start and end time on a given day are available for a reservation.  In my form I have the date displayed separately and then 2 input fields for start and end time.   In my rule in .extend, I have several issues.   The date isn't part of the form, so how do I get access to that in extend?  My second question is what is the best way to indicate which field is being validated  (is value start time or end time) ?

So far,my fields look like this:

```
                    <ValidationObserver>
                        <div class="w3-third">
                            <label>From</label>
                            <ValidationProvider vid='st'  rules="available:@st,@et" v-slot="{ errors}">                        
                                <dropdown id="starttime" :options="startTimeOptions" v-model="startTime"  @change="getDuration()"></dropdown> 
                                <span>{{ errors[0] }}</span>
                            </ValidationProvider>
                        </div>
                        <div class="w3-third  ">
                            <label>Until</label>
                            <ValidationProvider  vid="et" rules="available:@st,@et" v-slot="{ errors}">                        
                                <dropdown id="endtime" :options="endTimeOptions"  v-model="endTime" @change="getDuration()"></dropdown> 
                                <span>{{ errors[0] }}</span>

                            </ValidationProvider>

                        </div>
                    </ValidationObserver>
```

And my extend looks like this, I haven't gotten very far with this since I need the value for day as well:

```
         validate(value, {s, e} ) {

          var start= moment(day + "T" + s).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mmZ')
          var end = moment(day + "T" + e).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mmZ') 
              /* make call to server here to see if that is available. */
          return true;
         },
         params:[ 's', 'e']
       });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track.  Try switching to the [rules Object](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/advanced/rules-object-expression.html#cross-field-validation) instead of string for ValidationProvider, and pass in your `day` property there.

```
<ValidationProvider vid="st"
                    :rules="{'available':['@st','@et',day]}" 
                    v-slot="{ errors}">
```

Comment: This seems closer, but in my refs for the validation I am getting the first parameter, then the second shows as an array with the day as the second element. like this:{s: "09:00", e: Array(2)}

Comment: I just realized I forgot to add day to the params array. So that is working now.  Thanks so much!